# ASP.NET MVC Actionlink returns empty link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I'm having this issue and have searched Google and StackOverflow, but it seems I can't find a solution for it.

I'm having the following routes mapped in Global.asax.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       "posRoute", // Route name
       "pos/{guid}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Pos", action = "Index", guid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );

 routes.MapRoute(
       "foxRoute", // Route name
       "fox/{guid}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Fox", action = "Index", guid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I want to make a link with the HTML helper Actionlink but it keeps returning an empty link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "device")
```

returns

```
<a href="">Proceed</a>


@Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "device", "Fox" , new { guid = "test" })
```

returns

```
<a href="" guid="test">Proceed</a>
```

as the expected result is as follow:

```
<a href="/fox/index/test">Proceed</a>
```

or better

```
<a href="/fox/test">Proceed</a>
```

Comment: If you want to target a particular route, using Html.RouteLink instead of ActionLink might be a good option.

Comment: In my case, I wasn't specifying the area in routeValues. If you're using areas and trying to link to a controller in another area, do `@Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "device", "Fox", new { area = "Areaname", guid = "test" }, null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

so your code will be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "device", "Fox" , new { guid = "test" },null)
```

If you want to pass any HTML attributes like **CSS class/ ID of element**, you can replace the last parameter calue (null in our case) with that.

Also make sure that you have the generic route definition below your specific routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "posRoute", 
            "pos/{guid}", 
            new { controller = "Pos", action = "Index", 
            guid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "foxRoute", // Route name
            "fox/{guid}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Fox", action = "Index",
            guid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

routes.MapRoute("Default","{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional })
```

Comment: This also gives me '<a href="">Proceed</a>'

Comment: Do you have the generic route as the last one in global.asax other that these 2 ?

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: Cool. Even i added that to my answer. :)